# Pandas: slow when selecting from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that's created from a list of dictionaries, which I obtained from a database. I'm trying to use that as an in-memory database, which I query using the following function:

```
def filter_entities(df, name1, name2):
    key = ((df.name1 == name1) &
           (df.name2 == name2))

    rows = df.loc[key]
    if len(rows) == 0:
        return None
    return rows.iloc[0]
```

Doing that seems to be much slower than I expected. Even when testing on a couple of hundred rows, it takes about 1ms per call. I've tried setting an index on those columns when I create the dataframe but it didn't affect the performance:

```
entities.set_index(['name1', 'name2'], drop=False, inplace=True)
```

Here's a quick way to create a dataset for testing:

```
import random, string
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{
   'name1': ''.join([random.choice(string.letters) for i in range(10)]),
   'name2': ''.join([random.choice(string.letters) for i in range(10)]),
   'val1': random.randint(0, 2**16),
   'val2': random.randint(0, 2**16),
   'val3': random.randint(0, 2**16),
   } for j in range(1000)])

In[27]: %timeit filter_entities(df, df['name1'][100], df['name2'][100])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.91 ms per loop
```

I'm trying to find an efficient way to make queries on my data. Is there a better way to do this in pandas?

Comment: Can your provide a reproducible example? (some dummy data of the size you are already experiencing the problems)

Comment: BTW, the last of your function (`rows.iloc[0]`), is that correct? As this will only return the first row of your filtered data.

Comment: See my edit for a reproducible example. And yes, I'm looking for only one row, but removing that part that doesn't make it any faster.

Comment: Do you know that the combination of name1 and name2 will always be unique? Or is it possible that there multiple rows matching the selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the columns as the index does improve the performance for me.

With your original `filter_entities` function:

```
In [25]: %timeit filter_entities(df, df['name1'][100], df['name2'][100])

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.36 ms per loop
```

And after setting the columns as the index, and then indexing that frame:

```
In [26]: df2 = df.set_index(['name1', 'name2'])

In [27]: %timeit df2.loc[df['name1'][100], df['name2'][100]]
10000 loops, best of 3: 160 µs per loop
```

---

Note that a large portion of the time spent in the `filter_entities` function is used for the boolean comparison (creation of the `key`, and not for the indexing itself).

Second note: if the performance on this scale matters to you, then in many cases it is also useful to think about the larger picture if you need to access individual rows in this way repeatedly, or if you can do it more vectorized.

Comment: You're right, I was using the index wrong, as I thought it would speed up the creation of the boolean index, which it doesn't. I'll also take a look at vectorizing, as I need to do this quite a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  This can be performed in pandas.  I created some sample data for the example.

The following line subsets the dataframe for columns with 'name1' equal to bob and 'name2' equal to greg.

```
df[(df['name1'] == 'bob') & (df['name2'] == 'greg')]
```

Full Code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'name1': 'bob', 'name2':  'greg', 'value': 1},
        {'name1': 'bob', 'name2':  'greg', 'value': 2},
        {'name1': 'jim', 'name2':  'greg', 'value': 3},
        {'name1': 'bob', 'name2':  'greg', 'value': 4},
        {'name1': 'bob', 'name2':  'tim', 'value': 5},
        {'name1': 'bob', 'name2':  'jo', 'value': 6}]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print df[(df['name1'] == 'bob') & (df['name2'] == 'greg')]

      name1 name2  value
    0   bob  greg      1
    1   bob  greg      2
    3   bob  greg      4

def filter_entities(entities, name1, name2):
    key = ((entities.name1 == name1) &
           (entities.name2 == name2))

    rows = entities.loc[key]
    if len(rows) == 0:
        return None
    return rows.iloc[0]

%timeit test1 = df[(df['name1'] == 'bob') & (df['name2'] == 'greg')]
%timeit test2 = filter_entities(df, 'bob', 'greg')

100 loops, best of 3: 2.02 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.31 ms per loop
```

Comment: How is this different (in essence, as your also doing a boolean selection, but just in one line and not in a function) or faster as what the OP did?

Comment: The performance differences here are negligible. Why does iterating on 6 rows and comparing 2 values take 2ms? On my computer it takes 1µs using a python loop.

Answer (score 0):

Changing this line:

```
df[(df['name1'] == 'bob') & (df['name2'] == 'greg')]
```

To this:

```
df2 = df[(df['name1'] == 'bob')]
df3 = df2[(df2['name2'] == 'greg')]
```

reduced the time in half for me.